# Find and replace value in object by key?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have two objects:

```
const initialValue = {
  animal: null,
  weight: {
    kg: null,
    lbs: null,
  },
  sex: null,
  age: null,
  size: {
    height: null,
    width: null,
  }
}

const inputValues = {
  animal: 'cat',
  kg: 6,
  sex: 'male',
  height: 32,
  width: 57,
}
```

I want to take value from each available key in `inputValues` and replace corresponding in `initialValue`. Problem is that some keys are nested like kg/lbs and width/height. In future I might have deeper nesting. In this case how would be better to address these keys?

Comment: Flatten then merge?

Comment: Either change the input format, change the output format, or hardcode which key corresponds to which (nested) key

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function that will take the target object and the input values and:

1. If it detects a nested object, calls itself with the nested object as the target object
2. Otherwise, will check and see if the key of the object has values in the input and replace as needed.

See below for an example.  Note that this is a rudimentary quick pass-- you'd probably want something a bit more sophisticated with more checks, but it is a start.  Furthermore, please note that this *mutates the original target object*-- if this is not desirable, you would want to adjust appropriately.

```js
const replaceVals = (targetObj, inputObj) => {
  const inputKeys = Object.keys(inputObj);
  
  for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(targetObj)) {
    if (val && typeof val === 'object' && !Array.isArray(val)) {
      replaceVals(val, inputObj);
    } else {
      if (inputKeys.includes(key)) {
        targetObj[key] = inputObj[key];
      }
    }
  }
};

const initialValue = {
  animal: null,
  weight: {
    kg: null,
    lbs: null,
  },
  sex: null,
  age: null,
  size: {
    height: null,
    width: null,
  }
}

const inputValues = {
  animal: 'cat',
  kg: 6,
  sex: 'male',
  height: 32,
  width: 57,
}

replaceVals(initialValue, inputValues);

console.log(initialValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to start building your own model (class) and to use descriptive property names like below

I just added setters for weight kg & lbs as they change depending on each other. So, whenever you update one of them => the second must be updated as well

```js
class Animal {

  constructor(name, weight_kg, weight_lbs, sex, age, height, width) {
    this.name = name;
    this.weight_kg =  weight_kg || (weight_lbs * 0.454).toFixed(2);
    this.weight_lbs = weight_lbs || (weight_kg / 0.454).toFixed(2);
    this.sex = sex;
    this.age = age;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width; 
  }

  setWeightLbs(weight_lbs){
    this.weight_lbs = weight_lbs;
    this.weight_kg = (weight_lbs * 0.454).toFixed(2)
  }
  
  setWeightKg(weight_kg){
    this.weight_kg = weight_kg;
    this.weight_lbs = (weight_kg / 0.454).toFixed(2)
  }
} 

  let animal1 = new Animal('cat', 6,undefined, 'male', undefined, 32, 57 )
  
console.log(animal1);

animal1.setWeightLbs(1);

console.log(animal1);
```

Comment: Prefixing every property of an `Animal` with `animal_` is weird though. Use JS naming conventions, not Python ones.